# Convert google.maps.Map to static map link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to convert the currently viewed google.maps.Map to a static image link, so that I can fetch the image and, for example, embed it into a PDF?

I add some Markers with custom Icons on the Map, so I'm not sure if it really is possible.
If not, are there any workaraounds?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to do the same, well actually, I want to do the reversed. Turn a static map URL into a set of options for a dynamic map.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed. See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_screenshots

> Use of Google Maps imagery in printed materials **and offline media** is
>   subject to the Permission Guidelines published at:
>
> http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

you can request permission, but I don't think it's easy to obtain, unless you are a paying  business customer.

Comment: Perhaps printing in a PDF is not allowed, but Google has a static map API so you can easily embed <img>-maps for users without Javascript. Like the OP I would also like to know if you can easily convert a static map to a dynamic one or vice versa.